# Sophisticated Quartz Cron Expression

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, cron-task

I want to create an expression every n months that starts from the current month just for this year. I'm not looking for permanent offset which iterates only from the specified month through the end of the year.

For example; launching task every 3 months starts in July:

Unpleasant scenario:July,October,July,October..

What I want :July,October,January,april and so on..

Can I do it with Cron Expression?

Answer (score 0):

Cron expression-

**Every 3 month starting in July** - 0 0 0 ? 7/3 * *

Here 7- July Month and 3- Cycle. If task is staring from August then - 0 0 0 ? 8/3 * *

hope, it answers your question.

Comment: this exactly what I don't want, I don't need offset

Comment: ok. correct me if I am wrong. you want to start task from July..then expression  0 0 0 ? 7/3 * * is correct. it start in July then again starts in October, then January and then April. If you want to run for this year only then add 2020 at the end. expression would be - 0 0 0 ? 7/3 * 2020

Comment: No, this expression will iterate only from July to october permanently 2020,2021... not just just 2020

Comment: for all year - 0 0 0 ? JAN,APR,JUL,OCT * * and for current year only - 0 0 0 ? JAN,APR,JUL,OCT * 2020